# How to override custom css by parent css using local.xml?

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, css, xml

I have a simple `local.xml` that attempts to include a custom **wc_styles.css** in my head block, to apply for all pages in my site.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>

    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_css</type>
            <file>css/wc_styles.css</file>
        </action>

        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/wc_styles.css</stylesheet></action>

    </reference>


    </default>
</layout>
```

When viewing the source of my website, **wc_styles.css** is being included above all the parent themes css files (all within the HTML head tag), so my custom css rules get canceled out basically.

What is the proper way of getting a custom css to work?

**Edit Note:**

I'm merely trying to make look & feel changes to the Magento 1.9 RWD theme.
I've created the folders for my **subtheme** at

```
\app\design\frontend\wc\default

\skin\frontend\wc\default
```

My **local.xml** is placed at:

```
\app\design\frontend\warecompare\default\layout
```

My **wc_styles.css** is placed at:

```
\skin\frontend\warecompare\default\css
```

This is what the source code of my site looks like where u see my **wc_styles.css appearing above the parents styles.css**

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Home page</title>
<meta name="description" content="Default Description" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Magento, Varien, E-commerce" />
<meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW" />
<link rel="icon" href="http://localhost/mg1/skin/frontend/base/default/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://localhost/mg1/skin/frontend/base/default/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var BLANK_URL = 'http://localhost/mg1/js/blank.html';
    var BLANK_IMG = 'http://localhost/mg1/js/spacer.gif';
//]]>
</script>
<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/mg1/skin/frontend/base/default/css/et_advancedcompare/noreload.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/mg1/skin/frontend/wc/default/css/wc_styles.css" media="all" />
<!-- big heap of javascript includes here-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500,700,600" />
<!--[if  (lte IE 8) & (!IEMobile)]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/mg1/skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/styles-ie8.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/mg1/skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/madisonisland-ie8.css" media="all" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9) | (IEMobile)]><!-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/mg1/skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/styles.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/mg1/skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/madisonisland.css" media="all" />
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Note:
I actually have this as a duplicate question on StackOverflow before realizing that there as a Magento subdomain of StackExchange to ask this question on. Not sure how to delete the original question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25156808/magento-custom-css-overridden-by-parent-css-using-local-xml

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think your css is not working?
Remember, there are styles given by RWDs stylesheet.
So, if RWDs CSS tells

```
a {
color:red;
}
```

A link is red.
If your CSS says (nearly) the same the browser will be confused.

```
a {
color:green;
}
```

Now 2 css are written for the same thing.
So overwrite or redefine:

```
a {
color:green !important;
}

#id a {
color:green;
}
```

Ok?

Comment: this is so wrong, you can't even do worse than this.

Comment: What is your solution?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to RWD theme be your parent theme you need to create a theme.xml file under app/design/frontend/theme/package/etc with content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<theme>
    <parent>rwd/default</parent>
</theme>
```

otherwise I usually just copy all skin content from RWD theme to my new theme, so I edit stylesheet directly not rewrite it which results in huge amount of useless rewritten code.

please note, if you copy skin content, you still need a theme.xml because of you still want default fallback to RWD phtml files.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply go to `layout/page.xml` file and add following code at the end of the `head block`:

```
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/wc_styles.css</stylesheet></action>
```

Hope this helps.